# How to calculate financial year start and end dates from financial year's month end value?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a financial year's month end value `2`.

How would i calculate the financial year `DateTime startDate` and `DateTime endDate` from that value?

Comment: Err, what? Not sure that I understand, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 2, 1); // 1st Feb this year
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year+1, 2, 1).AddDays(-1); // Last day in January next year
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Yea thats almost perfect. Think you got the dates mixed up... ;-) The year end month is 2, so that means that the start date will be the fisrt of March, but thanks tho. I can work from that. =)

Comment: No his code will also yield the same result.. Feb-1 to Jan-31

Comment: @Shekhar: Yes i know, but his was more generic, therefor the correct 1. Your year was hard coded.

Comment: I am not saying why you accepted his answer (anyway my year was just a placeholder).. i was answering to your Comment "that he messed up the date".

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but this doesn't account for when you're in January of the next year, it will give you the next fiscal year instead of the current one... The only way this works 100% is if the fiscal year starts on Jan 1, just figured I'd mention that for the next guy.

Comment: This is not working when DateTime.Today is month January.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean Feb by 2.

This code should do this:

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2010,2,1);
DateTime end = start.AddMonths(12).AddDays(-1);
Console.WriteLine(start);
Console.WriteLine(end);
```

Output:

```
 01-Feb-10 12:00:00 AM

 31-Jan-11 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: How do you know that the financial year is 2010? Given just a month value and no other assumptions about the year...can't really give an answer!

Comment: OP need to mention that.. i have given answer according to asumptions

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version for calculating the Fiscal Year Start Date.  It checks the StartMonth against the current month, and will adjust the year.

```
private DateTime? FiscalYearStartDate() {
  int fyStartMonth = 2;
  var dte = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, fyStartMonth, 1); // 1st April this year

  if (DateTime.Today.Month >= fyStartMonth) {
    //Do nothing, since this is the correct calendar year for this Fiscal Year
  } else {
    //The FY start last calendar year, so subtract a year
    dte = dte.AddYears(-1);
  }

  return dte;
}
```

You can easily calculate the End Date like others have done, by adding +1 Year, and then subtracting 1 Day (thanks to Johannes Rudolph).

```
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year+1, 2, 1).AddDays(-1);
```

Comment: This is perfect answer. Generic solution to decide fiscal start date based on today if we know what is the FiscalStartMonth. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your current date is 14/01/2021
Then the Indian financial Year is 01/04/2020 to 31/03/2021

> Use the following code for perfect output.

```
DateTime CurrentDate = DateTime.Now;
int CurrentMonth = CurrentDate.Month;

if (CurrentMonth >= 4)//4 is the first month of the financial year.
{
txtFromDate.Text = new DateTime(CurrentDate.Year, 4, 1).ToString(CS.ddMMyyyy);
txtToDate.Text = new DateTime(CurrentDate.Year + 1, 4, 1).AddDays(-1).ToString(CS.ddMMyyyy);
}
else
{
txtFromDate.Text = new DateTime(CurrentDate.Year - 1, 4, 1).ToString(CS.ddMMyyyy);
txtToDate.Text = new DateTime(CurrentDate.Year, 4, 1).AddDays(-1).ToString(CS.ddMMyyyy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public  static (DateTime, DateTime) GetCurrentFinacialYearDateRange()
    {
        if(DateTime.Now.Month >= 7)
        {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 7, 1); // 1st July this year
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year + 1, 7, 1).AddDays(-1); // Last day in June next year
            return (startDate, endDate);
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime startDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year-1, 7, 1); // 1st July this year
            DateTime endDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 7, 1).AddDays(-1); // Last day in June next year
            return (startDate, endDate);
        }
        
    }
```